# POSTMAN mock server not refreshing/responding to new URL address

Tags: url, mocking, postman, response

I saw other posts with regard to POSTMAN here so hoping this is an OK place to ask this.
So I have my collection made, with my example responses from requests. I am using the mock servers to return my responses based on the URLs.

My request URL is `{{url}}/challenges/report?id=5` and in the example response I have saved, the URL is also `{{url}}/challenges/report?id=5` - HOWEVER I had to change the value or `{{url}}` from `localhost:5000` to `localhost:5000/v1`
I assume the mock server would just update, but it hasn't (and doesn't if I just delete the mock and create a new one) but it still responds to the url without the `/v1` but not with the `/v1`. I can see that the v1 url is coming up as `not found` in the mock logs
I guess how do I find my bug or how do I force an update on the mock server?

Comment: Have you created or update the example that uses that URL?

Comment: yes I updated it. I cant work out how to resync the mock - even if I recreate it